# Why does IMDB show 4 seasons of Lucifer?

Tags: lucifer

If the series ends after season three why does IMDB show a season four with ten episodes including one with "Eve"?

Comment: @AJ i assumed *Lucifer* as per the tag. if not then the question is unclear but i'll leave that in the hands of anyone who knows the series

Comment: @wil this is a new season which is yet to be released.

Answer (score 3):

### Because there is a fourth season, at least..

> On May 11, 2018, Fox cancelled Lucifer after three seasons. A month later, Netflix picked up the series for a fourth season of ten episodes, which is set to be released in 2019.
>
> <sup>[**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucifer_(TV_series))</sup>